# Como chamar um javascript dentro de outro?

Tags: javascript

Olá, como eu faço para fazer o seguinte javascript abaixo, funcionar em outro `.js` hospedado no meu domínio? Eu poderia simplesmente copiar o conteúdo dentro do `5feaf8db752a6f16f5f860f0bc7c60.js` e colocar no meu, mas o mesmo sofre frequentes alterações pela empresa.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://360popunder.com/5feaf8db752a6f16f5f860f0bc7c60.js?wkid=xxx&wid=xxx&k=xxx&traffic=0&cap=10&cid=downloads'></script>
```

Comment: O nome do arquivo tb muda?

Comment: Pq não carrega esse .js diretamente no seu site? O acesso é bloqueado?

Answer (score 1):

**Solução 1:**

Dentro do seu arquivo .JS, coloque o código abaixo:

```
document.write('<script src="http:\/\/360popunder.com\/5feaf8db752a6f16f5f860f0bc7c60.js?wkid=xxx&wid=xxx&k=xxx&traffic=0&cap=10&cid=downloads" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>');
```

Isso irá acrescentar o conteúdo do javascript na página.

---

**Solução 2:**

Uma outra solução é criar uma TAG script dinamicamente, onde é possível chamar o seu código assim que o arquivo for carregado:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function() {

        // seu codigo aqui

};
script.src = "http://360popunder.com/5feaf8db752a6f16f5f860f0bc7c60.js?wkid=xxx&wid=xxx&k=xxx&traffic=0&cap=10&cid=downloads";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelfischer/3uu4ztr9/)

---

**Solução 3**
Utilize o HeadJS (www.headjs.com) para carregar o arquivo e depois executar o seu código no load do arquivo JS. Exemplo:

```
head.load("http://360popunder.com/5feaf8db752a6f16f5f860f0bc7c60.js?wkid=xxx&wid=xxx&k=xxx&traffic=0&cap=10&cid=downloads", function() {

    // seu codigo aqui

});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelfischer/gqc7z8zf/)

ou mesmo carregar diversos arquivos:

```
head.load(["http://360popunder.com/5feaf8db752a6f16f5f860f0bc7c60.js?wkid=xxx&wid=xxx&k=xxx&traffic=0&cap=10&cid=downloads", "http://www.seusite.com/outro_arquivo.js"], function() {

    // seu codigo aqui

});
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Olá, testei mas o script não funcionou. Lembrando que preciso fazer com que o javascript passado, funcione em um que vou criar no meu domínio chamado de "exemplo.js".

Comment: Desculpe @Bernardo. entre no JsFiddle dos codigos acima. Você terá o exemplo deles com um alert()... pegue o codigo e insira dentro do seu arquivo exemplo.js

Comment: Olá @RafaelFischer ainda não funcionou. Como eu passei o script sem a 'key' de funcionamento, talvez vc não pode testar corretamente o funcionamento, estarei deixando aqui. // No lugar do "wkid=xxx" adicione "c49e9754a2c10d66ae436a121268dc3c" no lugar do primeiro xxx

Comment: @Bernardo, para mim funcionou. Veja nesse link do JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelfischer/3uu4ztr9/]. Eu coloquei o seu wkid e chamei o metodo contido no conteudo js, e coloquei dessa forma:
`alert(getParams(_0xa41a[0]).cap)`
Pelo o que eu percebi, esse arquivo .js tem seu conteúdo ofuscado através do Obfuscator, exemplo feito nesse link [https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx].

Comment: @Bernardo, continuando, e o problema é que da próxima vez que atualizarem esse arquivo .JS, é 99.9% de certeza que as variáveis irão ser alteradas, e aí, a variável `_0xa41a` que foi pego no `getParams()` não irá funcionar mais.

Comment: @Bernardo, se não for nada disso, por favor, explique melhor sua necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode user a biblioteca [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Para usá-la, basta fazer o download dela e incluí-la no seu index.html, substituindo static/js pela pasta onde estão seus javascripts:

```
<script data-main="static/js/main" src="static/js/require.js"></script>
```

Nesse exemplo, existiria um arquivo main.js, que seria o responsável por importar todos os outros arquivos, usando o RequireJS.
Então você deveria importar seu arquivo exemplo.js no main.js:

```
// main.js
require(['exemplo'], function() {
});
```

No arquivo em que você precisa do javascript externo, bastaria fazer algo assim:

```
// exemplo.js
require(['http://360popunder.com/5feaf8db752a6f16f5f860f0bc7c60.js?wkid=xxx&wid=xxx&k=xxx&traffic=0&cap=10&cid=downloads', 'outro_arquivo_necessário'], function(){
    // Toda sua lógica aqui dentro
});
```

Qualquer dúvida, ou se não funcionar pra você, pode deixar um comentário que tentamos descobrir o motivo.

Eu sugiro dar uma lida na documentação do RequireJS, caso você escolha utilizá-lo.

Comment: Olá, testei mas não funcionou. Lembrando que preciso fazer com que o javascript passado, funcione em um que vou criar no meu domínio chamado de "exemplo.js".

Comment: Você criou um arquivo main.js e importou seu exemplo.js nele? Eu atualizei a resposta pra deixar mais bem explicado